# Generating sound with javax.sound.sampled

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to generate sound with Java. In the end, I'm willing to continuously send sound to the sound card, but for now I would be able to send a unique sound wave.

So, I filled an array with 44100 signed integers representing a simple sine wave, and I would like to send it to my sound card, but I just can't get it to work.

```
int samples = 44100; // 44100 samples/s
int[] data = new int[samples];

// Generate all samples
for ( int i=0; i<samples; ++i )
{
  data[i] = (int) (Math.sin((double)i/(double)samples*2*Math.PI)*(Integer.MAX_VALUE/2));
}
```

And I send it to a sound line using:

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 1, 1, 44100, false);

Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
AudioInputStream inputStream = new AudioInputStream(ais,format,44100);
clip.open(inputStream);
clip.start();
```

My problem resides between these to code snippets. I just can't find a way to convert my `int[]` to an input stream!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly I think you want `short` samples rather than `int`:

```
short[] data = new short[samples];
```

because your `AudioFormat` specifies 16-bit samples. `short` is 16-bits wide but `int` is 32 bits.

An easy way to convert it to a stream is:

- Allocate a `ByteBuffer`
- Populate it using `putShort` calls
- Wrap the resulting `byte[]` in a `ByteArrayInputStream`
- Create an `AudioInputStream` from the `ByteArrayInputStream` and format

Example:

```
float frameRate = 44100f; // 44100 samples/s
int channels = 2;
double duration = 1.0;
int sampleBytes = Short.SIZE / 8;
int frameBytes = sampleBytes * channels;
AudioFormat format =
    new AudioFormat(Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                    frameRate,
                    Short.SIZE,
                    channels,
                    frameBytes,
                    frameRate,
                    true);
int nFrames = (int) Math.ceil(frameRate * duration);
int nSamples = nFrames * channels;
int nBytes = nSamples * sampleBytes;
ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(nBytes);
double freq = 440.0;
// Generate all samples
for ( int i=0; i<nFrames; ++i )
{
  double value = Math.sin((double)i/(double)frameRate*freq*2*Math.PI)*(Short.MAX_VALUE);
  for (int c=0; c<channels; ++ c) {
      int index = (i*channels+c)*sampleBytes;
      data.putShort(index, (short) value);
  }
}

AudioInputStream stream =
    new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.array()), format, nFrames*2);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(stream);
clip.start();
clip.drain();
```

Note: I changed your `AudioFormat` to stereo, because it threw an exception when I requested a mono line.  I also increased the frequency of your waveform to something in the audible range.

---

**Update** - the previous modification (writing directly to the data line) was not necessary - using a `Clip` works fine.  I have also introduced some variables to make the calculations clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play a simple Sound, you should use a SourceDataLine.

Here's an example:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
public class Sound implements Runnable {

  //Specify the Format as
  //44100 samples per second (sample rate)
  //16-bit samples,
  //Mono sound,
  //Signed values,
  //Big-Endian byte order
  final AudioFormat format=new AudioFormat(44100f,16,2,true,true);

  //Your output line that sends the audio to the speakers
  SourceDataLine line;

  public Sound(){
    try{
      line=AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
      line.open(format);
    }catch(LineUnavailableExcecption oops){
      oops.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Thread(this).start();
  }

  public void run(){
    //a buffer to store the audio samples
    byte[] buffer=new byte[1000];
    int bufferposition=0;

    //a counter to generate the samples
    long c=0;

    //The pitch of your sine wave (440.0 Hz in this case)
    double wavelength=44100.0/440.0;

    while(true){
      //Generate a sample
      short sample=(short) (Math.sin(2*Math.PI*c/wavelength)*32000);

      //Split the sample into two bytes and store them in the buffer
      buffer[bufferposition]=(byte) (sample>>>8);
      bufferposition++;
      buffer[bufferposition]=(byte) (sample & 0xff);
      bufferposition++;

      //if the buffer is full, send it to the speakers
      if(bufferposition>=buffer.length){
        line.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);
        line.start();
        //Reset the buffer
        bufferposition=0;
      }
    }
    //Increment the counter
    c++;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    new Sound();
  }
}
```

In this example you're continuosly generating a sine wave, but you can use this code to play sound from any source you want. You just have to make sure that you format the samples right. In this case, I'm using raw, uncompressed 16-bit samples at a sample rate of 44100 Hz. However, if you want to play audio from a file, you can use a Clip object

```
public void play(File file){
  Clip clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
  clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
  clip.loop(1);
}
```